# Multinomial Naive Bayes in Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes, supervised-learning

I have a set of features in which one of the features is a negative value. I intend to use Multinomial Naive Bayes for classification of my text document but the negative feature throws an error. Can I use Gaussian Naive Bayes for this setting of text classification?

Comment: What does this value mean ? Is it part of your text ? I don't get it

Comment: It's a feature. I am working on classifying edits on a document. The feature is the size_increment of the document due to the edit. Hence, it can be negative when the edit removes some words.

Comment: Can you show us the error and what you've tried ?